# DrawerToggle is not set (or not visible)

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to use a `NavigationDrawer` inside a `ListActivity`, so this is basically my `Layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="265dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#232833"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />



 <ListView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@android:id/list"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
 android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
 android:dividerHeight="10dp"
 android:choiceMode="singleChoice">
 </ListView>

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

After initializing the `Drawer` no errors occur, however, there's no `DrawerToggle` in the `ActionBar`. What could be a possible reason? `ActionBar` and `Drawer` setup:

```
          private void initDrawer(){
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.dr_open, R.string.dr_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
           //TODO
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            //TODO
        }

    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    lvDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
            lvDrawerList.setDivider(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.drawer_list_divider));
    lvDrawerList.setDividerHeight(4);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DRAWER_ITEMS);
    lvDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
}


      private void initActionBar(){
    ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setTitle("News");
    ab.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo));
    ab.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ab_main_bg));
}
```

**UPDATE** I figured out that I actually can open the `Drawer` with a swipe gesture, the `Toggle` is still missing from the `ActionBar` however

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but you've got your ListViews switched. The Drawer should be listed second.

Comment: just swapped them, no changes. I think it doesn't matter since both ListViews are found using their ids. I can also access both by code without getting an NPE, however I can't open the drawer list since the toggle is missing

Comment: I'm not sure of the actual problem, but in a DrawerLayout, order definitely matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to use `ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` to get the `DrawerToggle` working. Maybe this answer will help someone who's experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `mDrawerToggle.syncState()` is called in the wrong method. You should call it from `onPostCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

You should definitively take a look at the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Comment: already moved it to `onPostCreate()`, the issue with the `Toggle` not being visible still persists